# how to find and click this element on the DOM with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this element which I need to click on.
the id is not constant and regenerating differently each time the button appears.
searching by class gives too many options.
what will be a good way to locate it and click it?
the element:

```
<input type="button" class="simpleInputPushButton" value=OK id="ext-gen141">
```

just to clarify, I'm using selenium to automate the site, from some reason Selenium is getting this element as not displayed, hence i need to use JS. Jquery will bot be possible in this case.

Comment: Find a parent component that has a fixed id and then use class selectors?

Comment: You cna use a composite selector to uniquely identify button. Try `parentSelector input[type="button"].className` or `input[type="button"][attributeName~="attrValue"].className` or something similar

Answer (score 0):

You can get that element by its `value`. I believe the `value` of the element will be same:

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('input[value=OK]');
console.log(elem);
//then assign click event
elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('clicked elem with id ' + this.id);
})
```

```html
<input type="button" class="simpleInputPushButton" value=OK id="ext-gen141">
```

Comment: when i  run this on console it gives undefined
var elem = document.querySelector('input[value=OK]')

Comment: Do you have the input element with value `OK` at that time in the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element using `document.querySelector`.  The attached `onclick` is just for testing

```js
let m = document.querySelector('input[value="OK"]').click()

function test() {
  alert('Hello')
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="simpleInputPushButton" onclick='test()' value='OK' id="ext-gen141">
```

Comment: the first line: let m = document.querySelector('input[value=OK]')
return undefined

Answer (score -1):

Get this element by ID and trigger click event on it

```
document.getElementById('ext-gen141').click();
```

Comment: *the id is not constant and regenerating*. OP has clearly said ID will not work

Comment: Send some parent and siblings element so we can try something on it to detect it

Comment: So does this not make the answer void?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a combination of selectors to uniquely identify an element uniquely:

- Based on Parent selector:

  `div.parentClassName input[type="button"].simpleInputPushButton`
- Based on partial attribute value matching:

  - StartsWith

    `input[type="button"][id^="ext-gen"].simpleInputPushButton`
  - EndsWith

    `input[type="button"][id$="-141"].simpleInputPushButton`
  - Contains

    `input[type="button"][id~="gen"].simpleInputPushButton`

Comment: i don't know how to use it inside a querySelector

Comment: @DotanRaz If you can share a bit more of  HTML, we can help you form a selector. Also to reply to your comment, a selector is a string which, in your case would be unique. So you can directly use it. Using it is not a challenge, making a selector is.

Comment: @DotanRaz For your reference:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector